# LDAP: Get groups of a member

Tags: filter, ldap

I need to get all groups a member is assigned to via LDAP.
As filter I tried:

```
(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(uniqueMember=uid=myUserName,ou=service,o=company,c=DE))
```

Unfortunal this doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

uniqueMember is not an attribute of the objectClass groupOfNames, it's the attribute for objectClass groupOfUniqueNames.
member is the attribute for groupOfNames.
This said, several LDAP directory services do provide an operational attribute that list all the groups a user is member of, directly from the user entry. 
In MS AD, it's the memberOf attribute. In OpenDJ and Sun Directory, it's the isMemberOf attribute.